# Sobre responder a lo no preguntado

Tags: discusión, respuesta

Observo que hay tendencia a *sobre-responder*; es decir, si la pregunta es

> ¿ Porqué no puedo salir del foreach con un return en Javascript ?

He notado que se suelen dar respuestas a detalles no relevantes para la pregunta: por ejemplo:

- Usa variables con nombres explicativos ...
- Es mejor usar un `for( )` por X Y Z ...
- Usa `let` y no `var` para mantener tus variables en el ámbito mas pequeño posible ...
- No uses `function( )`, usa funciones flecha `( ) => { }` ...
- ...

Al margen de lo que opine personalmente sobre ese tipo de respuestas, hay un problema **práctico** con ellas: **no se pueden usar para marcar duplicados**.

Me ha pasado recientemente (no ahora mismo, y no encuentro la pregunta en cuestión). Preguntas que claramente son duplicados de otras (o al menos yo lo veo claro), buscarlas ... y ver que no se pueden usar, puesto que de los 30 párrafos que tienen, solo 1 de ellos trata el problema real.

Personalmente, cuando busco una respuesta a algún problema en el sitio inglés, suelo *ignorar* las respuestas que se alargan. Busco una solución a **mi** problema, un problema concreto. Y quiero una solución concreta, no un compendio de buenas prácticas.

En alguna publicación en *meta* leí que la idea del sitio es **no ser un foro al uso**, en los que para obtener una solución hay que buscar entre 250 *post* repartidos en 7 páginas.

Pues, a mi juicio, las respuestas en las que se ofrece ayuda sobre temas no solicitados es mas o menos lo mismo, pero concentrado en una sola publicación: como dije antes, de los 30 párrafos, solo 1 trata el problema. Y **ningún** usuario aceptará que esa pregunta es sobre su mismo problema:

> ¡ En esa respuesta hablan de muchas cosas, pero no de mi problema !

¿ Podría tomarse como *pauta a seguir* el responder **exclusivamente** a lo que se pregunta ? ¿ O estoy totalmente equivocado y es preferible continuar respondiendo a lo que no se ha preguntado ?

Comment: Es como si un auto para a tu lado para preguntarte una dirección. Tú le das las señas, pero también le avisas que lleva el neumático trasero desinflado. No te lo preguntaron, pero igual es útil informarlo.

Comment: Yo lo veo mas bien como poner un cartel en una calle informando de la distancia a muchos sitios ... cuando la calle solo te lleva a uno de ellos. El cartel se quedará ahí para siempre, aunque los sitios de los que informa pueden incluso desaparecer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Al margen de lo que opine personalmente sobre ese tipo de respuestas, hay un problema práctico con ellas: no se pueden usar para marcar duplicados.

Muchas preguntas se responden con cosas que le quitan *portabilidad* a la respuesta, o bien hay preguntas que se responden en base al caso **específico** de la pregunta.

Varias preguntas que he visto se pueden marcar como duplicados de otras que ya se han respondido. Sin embargo, no se puede por que cada pregunta/respuesta es un caso en particular. Debido a la ausencia de una respuesta general, hay preguntas que tienen la misma solución y no se marcan como duplicadas.

Ejemplos:

- [*¿Cómo utilizar funciones con tkinter?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/83102/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-funciones-con-tkinter)
- [*Cambiar variable con un botón en Tkinter*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/17621/cambiar-variable-con-un-bot%c3%b3n-en-tkinter)
- [*por que en este código TKinter no puede volver una variable de sting a float para usarlo con math*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375604/por-que-en-este-c%c3%b3digo-tkinter-no-puede-volver-una-variable-de-sting-a-float-par)

Con los títulos que tienen las preguntas, una respuesta para [*vincular una función a un botón en tkinter*](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01xaehQHE9brUPKC3cUyV_dA5YgCg%3A1599177042868&ei=UoFRX9q2NK-m5wKjnaqQBg&q=como+vincular+una+funcion+a+un+boton+de+tkinter&oq=como+vincular+una+funcion+a+un+boton+de+tkinter&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECCMQJ1D4iw5Y240OYMmYDmgAcAB4AIABmgGIAb8EkgEDMC40mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjap8rcls7rAhUv01kKHaOOCmIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) es difícil de encontrar.

Entonces mi punto es que, **"sobreresponder" quita las posibilidad de una solución general.** Si la respuesta de una pregunta menciona algo relacionado con el caso en **específico** en cuestión, evita que luego se pueda usar como referencia para otras preguntas con otros casos (marcar como duplicadas de esta).

Obviamente no se puede dar una respuesta general que solucione un problema en específico siempre, pero hay que considerar dar respuestas que le puedan servir luego a otros usuarios. Cuando se hacen observaciones al código de la pregunta, la respuesta solo le va a servir a un a persona.

Me queda claro que a veces las preguntas no se ubican bien debido al titulo que llevan. Pienso que hay que editar y responder para que la pregunta le pueda servir a alguien más que a la persona que formuló la pregunta, aún más importante **que la pueda encontrar otra persona.**

> He notado que se suelen dar respuestas a detalles no relevantes para la pregunta: por ejemplo:
>
> - Usa variables con nombres explicativos ...
> - Es mejor usar un for( ) por X Y Z ...
> - Usa let y no var para mantener tus variables en el ámbito mas pequeño posible ...
> - No uses function( ), usa funciones flecha ( ) => { } ...
> - ...

No está mal dar una recomendación, lo ideal es mencionarlo y adjuntar un enlace a una fuente que justifique esto. Lo que en **mi opinión personal** está mal es decir "te dejo el código completo corregido", y después haberle cambiado el nombre alas variables y funciones, o cualquier otro cambio brusco. Cuando el código de la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con el motivo de la búsqueda en Google de una persona.

Entonces estoy de acuerdo contigo, pienso que deben de haber preguntas con títulos claros, con solo el código relevante (si es que involucra código), y **respuestas que respondan al problema y que le puedan servir a otra persona.**

> Personalmente, cuando busco una respuesta a algún problema en el sitio inglés, suelo ignorar las respuestas que se alargan. Busco una solución a mi problema, un problema concreto. Y quiero una solución concreta, no un compendio de buenas prácticas.

Cuando en Google se busca un *¿Por qué?* o un ¿Qué? se espera una explicación amplia. Por otro lado, cuando solo se copia y pega el error de la terminal **no**.

Comment: Te has explicado mejor que yo. Aunque mi queja no es sobre las explicaciones detalladas, sino sobre explicaciones a lo no preguntado. En el caso de ejemplo, advertencias como `Usa variables con nombres explicativos ...` sobrarían. Las explicaciones detalladas son **siempre** bienvenidas y deseables :-)

Comment: Respuesta aceptada ... pero por el número de votos tanto de la pregunta como de la respuesta, me temo que todo seguirá igual :-(

Answer (score 1):

El 99% de los problemas de programación se pueden explicar con analogías de coches.

---

Imagina que diriges un taller de coches y un cliente viene con un coche con el parachoques caído, las pastillas de freno desgastadas, los neumáticos con baja presión y los niveles bajo mínimos; el cliente afirma que su problema es que la dirección del coche va dura.

¿Qué haces?

- **A)** Le revisas la dirección y te despides del cliente.
- **B)** Le revisas la dirección, le reparas el parachoques, le cambias las pastillas de freno, le inflas los neumáticos y le rellenas el aceite, refrigerante y demás.

Si tu respuesta es **A**, estás efectivamente respondiendo a las peticiones del cliente, ni más ni menos, pero estarás permitiendo que dicho cliente conduzca un ataúd rodante poniendo en peligro su seguridad y la de otros. Si tu respuesta es **B**, además de responder a las peticiones del cliente, evitas que le surjan nuevos problemas y contribuyes a hacer de la carretera un lugar más seguro.

---

Imaginemos una situación en nuestra amada página, ante una pregunta de programación con dos respuestas idénticas ¿Cuál crees que aporta más conocimiento y valor?

- **A)** La respuesta que describe a la perfección la solución a las dudas del usuario que preguntó.
- **B)** La respuesta que describe a la perfección la solución a las dudas del usuario que preguntó y que adicionalmente corrige otros problemas evidentes en el código del usuario que preguntó.

Si prefieres la **A**, estás efectivamente respondiendo a la duda del usuario que preguntó, ni más ni menos, pero estarás permitiendo que dicho usuario produzca un código que podría poner en peligro su prestigio como programador y complicar la vida de otros. Si prefieres la **B**, además de responder a las peticiones del usuario que preguntó, evitas que le surjan nuevos problemas y contribuyes a hacer de la comunidad de programación un lugar mejor.

Comment: ¿ Y cuando puedo usar la respuesta **B** como destino de otras preguntas *duplicadas* ? Usando tu analogía, es como si un cliente te pide un presupuesto para un pinchazo, y le das una copia de la factura de otro cliente que, ciertamente, tenía un pinchazo ... y los amortiguadores rotos, 2 bombillas fundidas, y el disco de embrague gastado. El nuevo cliente saldrá *espantado*.

Comment: Puedes usar la respuesta **B** como destino de preguntas duplicadas cuando el problema que motivó la pregunta sea el mismo en ambos casos, el corazón de la pregunta, por así decirlo.